# get method in restful service , return {}

Tags: rest, jakarta-ee

I want to pass an JSONObject from restful service to a restful client . Here is pice of my service code :

```
@GET
@Path("/getJson")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public JSONObject getJson() {
    try {
        JSONObject json=new JSONObject();
        json.put("PoprocessingCode", "123456789");
        json.put("TransactionAmount", "0000000");
        System.out.println(json);
        return json;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
}
```

and here is pice of my restful client :

```
    Client c = Client.create();
    WebResource resource = c.resource("http://localhost:8080/TestJsonService/jaxrs/JsonService/getJson");
    JSONObject json=new JSONObject();
    json=resource.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE).get(JSONObject.class);
    try {
        System.out.println("json.getString = "+json.getString("PoprocessingCode"));
    } catch (JSONException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

when I ran it , I get this error :

> org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["PoprocessingCode"] not found.
>       at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:459)
>       at org.json.JSONObject.getString(JSONObject.java:640)
>       at JsonClient.main(JsonClient.java:30)

I tested my service by Test with "REST Web Service Explorer" in myeclipse and recognized get method in service T returned just this

> {}

and there isn't anything in it and it is empty , I don't know why?!

please guide me in order to solve it.

thanks...

Comment: I has sent entity object and also String value from service to client . But when use JSOBObjsect same as entity object , it doesn't work !

Comment: Is it printing the generated JSON on the server side at System.out? Why not try System.out on the Client code as well and see what it prints? Also, open the URL in the browser and debug Request and Response in the Network tab to see what is going out and coming in.

Answer (score 1):

```
    Please pass the JsonObject in this form, this will work :
        @Path("Excel")
        @POST
        @GET
        @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        public String ExportToExcel(String jsonString)

    And post this using REST Console.

In case of : 
JsonObject then use this --->

@Path("/rename")
    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Event renameEvent(Event newEvent)

And the object that you pass from the REST CONSOLE should be of following pattern :

{"measures":null,"eventScenarioId":2016,"timeId":20378,"promoPrice":1.979734,"oiAllowancePerunit":0.0,"productId":7158,"scanAllowancePerUnit":0.0,"eventProductStrategy":[{"name":"FND","tsId":4,"tsACV":10.0,"eventProductScenarioId":5069,"id":3},{"name":"TPR","tsId":1,"tsACV":0.0,"eventProductScenarioId":5069,"id":4},{"name":"DISPLAY","tsId":3,"tsACV":2.0,"eventProductScenarioId":5069,"id":2},{"name":"FEATURE","tsId":2,"tsACV":9.0,"eventProductScenarioId":5069,"id":1}],"addEstimatedIncrementalUnits":0.0,"shippedBaseUnits":4365.000000000001,"edShelfPrice":1.979734,"eventFixedCost":0.0,"shippedUnitPct":100.0,"edlpPricePerUnit":0.0,"manuFixedCost":0.0,"customerId":null,"id":5069}
```